# Best way to handle exceptions in functon args?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I was recently coding a few Python 3.x programs and I wonder what is the best way of handling simple exceptions in python function args. In this example I'm going with checking if inserted value can be converted to int. I've come up with two ways of doing this:

```
def test_err_try(x, y, z):

    try:
        int(x)
        int(y)
        int(z)
    except ValueError or TypeError:    #try handler
        return 'Bad args.'
    ##code##
```

or

```
def test_err_if(x, y, z):

    if type(x) != int or type(y) != int or type(z) != int:    #if handler
        raise ValueError('Bad args.')
    else:
        ##code##
```

I know that there is a difference in what the handlers are returning - in the first case it's just string 'Bad args.' and in the second it is ValueError exception.
What is the best (or rather simplest and shortest) way? First, second or neither and there is a better one?

Comment: Instead of the latter you can use `assert` (although simple `type(x) == int` won't tell you if you can convert the argument to `int`), but technically the first one is more 'Pythonic'. Either way, tho, I'd suggest you to think of your use case - if it's more likely than not to encounter attributes that do not pass your desired validation, do it with `if` otherwise do it with `try...except` - the ultimate goal being using the least amount of processing for most use cases.

Comment: I wonder just now, for example, if I have `x += 1` in the code without checking the exception and the type still isn't an int (or float), the program will return Error anyways, so I'm not sure if I should check for anything at all.   Is error catching useful in very long programs only (like x is used in the beginning, y after 1000 lines of code and z is just printed in the end - now it's worth to check it at the beginning, to be sure that the code won't run and error in the end?)

Comment: That purely depends on your business logic - error handling exists so you can control the flow of your code when an error occurs. There no reason to capture an exception in case of an unrecoverable failure only to raise another such exception - except maybe to unify exceptions so users of your functions don't need to capture multiple exceptions for multiple cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on your use case.  If you are building a function which will be exposed to an end user, then the `try` `except` block offers more functionality because it will allow any variable which can be converted to an int.  In this case I would suggest raising an error rather than having the function return a string:

```
try:
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    z = int(z)
except ValueError:
    raise TypeError("Input arguments should be convertible to int")
```

If the function is meant for internal use within your program, then it is best to use the `assert` statement because its evaluation can be disabled once you are finished debugging your program.

```
assert type(x) is int
assert type(y) is int
assert type(z) is int
```